# Problem using whisper through google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-whisper

I started using whisper a couple of weeks ago through google colab, but a couple of days ago it stopped working. The blurbs that I'd been using are:

- Install Whisper AI:
  !pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
  !sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
- Run Whisper AI:
  !whisper "ENTER FILE NAME HERE" --model medium

This would work for both video and audio files. Now please bear in mind that I'm a coding virgin, I don't know how to code, all I did was follow the instruction on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SQV-B83tPU.

So, if anyone has the up to date whisper install and run blurbs that I can use and that actually work for google colab, I'd be soooo grateful if you could provide them.

Thanks!